# Count down to 24 hours

Tags: swift, date, swiftui

So I know how to check if two dates are older than 24 hours.

However what I would like to do is make it tell me how many hours are left until the user can re-enter the competition.

I currently use this method.

```
let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: UserSettings().lockRequest, to: Date()).hour!
    let diffmin = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: UserSettings().lockRequest, to: Date()).minute!
```

Note I sent the `UserSettings().lockRequest` to the date / time that the user entered the competition.

Then I check the current Date. What I am wanting to do is say the following on screen.

```
Text("Your Entered To WIN!").font(.largeTitle)
 Text("You have already submitted your request.\nPlease come in \(24-diff) Hours and (diffmin) Minutes.")
```

I also tried this

```
Text("\(Date().timeIntervalSince(UserSettings().lockRequest))")
```

But it printed a really long number. 81,xxx

Comment: Why not add .hour to the second code row and then extract both hours and minutes?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean.

Comment: Personally I'd use `Date().timeIntervalSince(Date)`, this will give the time difference in seconds (as a `Double`). Then I'd use a `DateComponentsFormatter` to format the difference, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215882/ios-how-to-create-countdown-time-hours-minutes-seccond-swift-4/52216136#52216136)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is first to add one day to `UserSettings().lockRequest`

```
let nextAvailableDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: UserSettings().lockRequest)!
```

Then calculate the difference from now (in hours **and** minutes)

```
let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: Date(), to: nextAvailableDate)
```

Finally check if the hours are < 24. If so show the text

```
if diff.hour! < 24 {
    Text("Your Entered To WIN!").font(.largeTitle)
    Text("You have already submitted your request.\nPlease come in \(diff.hour!) Hours and \(diff.minute!) Minutes.")
}
```

Both exclamation marks are safe because the date components `hour` and `minute` do definitely exist.

Comment: I like that approach - It's a lot less code and easy to implement.

Thanks